# Method to measure specific gravity above refractometer range?

Tags: cider, specific-gravity, measurements, refractometer

I purchased [this refractometer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BNNQTYW4) for use in brewing hard cider.  The recipe I'm using involves adding sugar and then boiling down the juice by about 1/3.  After reducing the liquid, the specific gravity is above the maximum (1.120) for this refractometer; there's no blue in the eyepiece at all.

My [got C's in high school chemistry in the 1970s] brain thinks that if I mix equal parts test liquid and deionized water, then double whatever is to the right of the decimal, I should arrive at the correct measurement.  For example, if the 1:1 diluted liquid measures 1.096, the undiluted S.G. would be 1.192.  Is this right, or am I nuts?

Comment: Have you made this recipe before? Targeting a SG of 1.192 seems absolutely insane to me.

Comment: @rob it's experimental.  But it's bubbling happily away...  I have made similar and it has come out OK.  This batch is the first time I've ever measured SG though.  My Q is just about whether this measurement method is accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your idea is correct.  I would have recommended exactly the same technique.

Comment: I also checked with some people IRL and this seems to be the consensus.  I guess high school was good for something after all! :- )